# creating a nested tibble

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, quosure, nested-tibble

I would like to create a tibble that contains a nested tibble, but also a column outside the nested tibble that refers to a column header within the nested tibble.  This is what I mean

```
library(tidyverse)
tib <- tibble(dat = list(tibble(xvar = 1, freq = 2, rate = 3.2)),
              yvar = c(freq)
             )
```

However I get the error
"Error in eval_tidy(xs[[j]], mask) : object 'freq' not found"

I want to use the cell contents of tib$yvar as the input into a function that contains a ggplot function eg.

```
plot_datapoint <- function(dat = tib){
     dat_tib <- dat %>% unnest(cols = c(dat))

ggplot(dat_tib, aes(x=xvar, y = yvar)+
geom_point()
```

I believe the solution has something to do with quosures, but don't know how to implement it.

Comment: the error message is pretty clear - you need to define the object `freq` first. How is the data structured with which you intend to create that tibble? Your approach of first creating a tibble and then unnesting it before passing it to ggplot seems rather ... not ideal to me.

Comment: Would `tibble(dat = list(tibble(xvar = 1, freq = 2, rate = 3.2)), yvar = pluck(dat, 1, "freq"))` be what you want?

Comment: @Bas this is pretty nice. pluck certainly wasn't on my radar till now. seems pretty cool that it can evaluate this as such

Comment: That solution looks pretty impressive @Bas. Thank you for offering this solution!